# How can we use std::transform, if we don't want to transform each element into one transformed element, but two?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator

How can we use `std::transform`, if we don't want to transform each element into *one* transformed element, but *two*?

The following pseudo code illustrates what I want to achieve

```
std::transform(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), std::back_inserter(b), [](T const& x) {
    return f(x) and g(x);
});
```

Of course, I could invoke `std::transform` two times, but that would be annoying. Maybe we need to provide a custom *inserter*. Any other option?

Comment: You could write an iterator adapter (like the back insert iterator you already use) that does the right thing. However, the IMHO best approach is to write a simple loop, because it is a construct that can easily be read and understood by any programmer from just the context.

Comment: @0xbadf00d See my profile and in my profile there is a reference to my article in ACCU Overload. You could use iterator adapter iterator_pair that I proposed.:)

Answer (score 7):

`transform` is only for doing a one-to-one transformation. A custom inserter wouldn't help you anyway since `transform` is implemented something like this:

```
while (first1 != last1) {
    *d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++); // you have no way to write
                                      // more than one element
}
return d_first;
```

You would actually have to write a custom iterator for `a` to iterate over each element twice, and then keep state in your functor to know if you're on the `f` state or the `g` state. You can see how complicated this is getting.

Anything outside of simple 1-1 transformations, you should you just use a `for` loop:

```
for (const auto& x : a) {
    b.push_back(f(x));
    b.push_back(g(x));
}
```

And even for simple 1-1 transformations, I think a simple `range-for` expression wins too.

You could additionally write your own `transform` that takes an arbitrary number of functors:

```
template <typename InIt, typename OutIt, typename... Functors>
void transform(InIt first, InIt last, OutIt d_first, Functors... fs)
{
    while (first != last) {
        apply(*first, d_first, fs...);
        first++;
    }
}
```

with;

```
template <typename In, typename OutIt>
void apply(const In&, OutIt ) { }

template <typename In, typename OutIt, typename F, typename... Functors>
void apply(const In& in, OutIt& out, F f, Functors... fs)
{
    *out++ = f(in);
    apply(in, out, fs...);
}
```

used as ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c976ae2a58879fb)):

```
transform(a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(b), f, g);
```

Comment: Then, we might ask the question why we should use `std::transform` at all - even in the case of a one-to-one transformation.

Comment: Then put this loop in function with a new name and an iterator interface and you have a double-transform for all time!

Comment: @0xba the advantage of `std::transform` at this point is much smaller, now that we have range for.  You can swap the output iterator easily I suppose.

Comment: @0xbadf00d std::transform is cleaner and the purpose of the programmer could be understood easier. but more importantly, as of new c++ standards and compilers lots of std algorithms can use parallel execution policy by adding a simple parameter to them, which is not possible with simple loops.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such cases you can use standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<numeric>`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve( 2 * std::extent<decltype( a )>::value );

    std::accumulate( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ),
                     std::back_inserter( v ),
                     []( auto it, auto x )
                     {
                        return *it++ = x * x, *it++ = x * x * x, it;  
                     } );

    auto it = v.begin();                     
    for ( int x : a )
    {
        std::cout << x << '\t' << *it++ << '\t';
        std::cout << *it++ << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1   1   1
2   4   8
3   9   27
4   16  64
5   25  125
6   36  216
7   49  343
8   64  512
9   81  729
10  100 1000
```

Comment: You are unnecessarily adding up the elements so this is sub optimal

Comment: @Otomo  I have not understood what you mean.

Comment: Accumulate is a algorithm to determine the sum of all elements in the container. You are not using it the way it is intended and you are unnecessarily computing the sum.

Comment: @Otomo  Again I have understood nothing. Could you be more precise and say where the sum is computed? Also accumulate means only accumulate. For example in the program I showed it accumulates elements in a vector. Your point of view is very defective.

Comment: @Otomo It is true that Vlad is not using accumulate as intended, but there is absolutely no "sum" here.

Comment: Right, sry, no sum here, but the specification of the algorithm sais that the function / lambda given must not have side effects

Comment: @Otomo  You are wrong. The specification says nothing about this. It only says that elements shall not be modified. And there is no any side effect.:)

Comment: Writing elements to another vector IS a side effect ... Your solution is highly dangerous. If someone else sees the function call `std::accumulate` he will most likely expect something to be "accumulated" like the algorithm is meant to be used. Would you expect the sort function to write to another vector? With lambdas you can use it the same way you used `accumulate` here. Would you do that, too?

Comment: @Otomo And it indeed accumulates.:)  It accumulates values in the vector. As for sort function then there is sort_copy algorithm.:) As I already said your point of view is very defective. For example with accumulate any operation can be used. This algorithm is used for very broad area of tasks. For example very often it is a good replacement for std:;count and so on.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No it doesn't accumulate anything. Accumulate is the summation of the elements. That's how this algorihm is meant to be used. `std::for_each` is a better fit. You do not expect accumulate to **generate** or **fill** another vector. This is bad practice. Accumulate is expected to return it's result by its interface. It seems like you don't know what *side effect* means. If you would use it like `auto res = std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), std::vector{}, [](auto vec, auto value){//dosomething; vec.push_back(something); });` it would satisfy the interface. Without side effects.

Comment: @Otomo You are mistaken. To accumulate is not equivalent to sum up something. std::accumulate allows to use any operation, For example you can "accumulate" character arrays in a string or use std::minus and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76255/discussion-between-otomo-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @Otomo I am sorry. It is too late in Moscow. You can read an article that is referenced in my profile. There is an example of using std::accumulate for example with string literals.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow One last time. It is required not to have side effects. A side effect is everything that manipulates something outside of the function. You are right that it can be used in this scenario, but not like you suggest. You have side effects which are not allowed by the **C++ Standard**. Yes, you can to it this way and it works, but it is bad practice and confusing for someone who reads your code. Return the result and don't use side effects or choose another algorithm (`std::for_each` for example).

Comment: @otomo can you quote the standard where it mandates no side effects?  Vlad claims it just must not modify elements in the source range, which is a far more lax requirement than your claim.  Barring some evidence, vlad's position seems more credible (no modify is a common requirement, like `remove_if`: I am unaware of 'pure' requirements in the standard)

Comment: Okay, it seems like I misunderstood the standard. You are right.